# Prevent text wrapping after kable table with kableExtra(position='float_left')

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to put multiple tables on a single line in a R Markdown document. I'm able to do that by `kable %>% kableStyling(... ,position='float_left')` and the tables line up nicely across a page:

[image]

However, when resuming text after these tables (headings, text, anything, really), it starts to the right of the last table on the line. Here is a simple example:

````
---
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
  require(kableExtra)
``` and
```{r Test, echo=F}
  d1 <- data.frame(Item=c('A','B','C'),Value = c(1,2,3),Units=c('X','Y','Z'))
  knitr::kable(d1,format='html') %>%
    kable_styling(position='float_left',full_width=F)
```

## Next heading
````

[image]

I would have expected that `## Next heading` would start on a new line. This happens both with format='html' and format='latex':

Answer (score 2):

As stated by the `kableExtra` [documentation](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html) about the `float` options:

> You can also wrap text around the table using the float-left or float-right options.

So the behaviour you are witnessing is as would be expected for the package.

An easy workaround for your situation is to make the last table on each line use the argument `position='left'` instead of `position='float_left'`

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
  require(kableExtra)
```

```{r Test, echo=F}
  d1 <- data.frame(Item=c('A','B','C'),Value = c(1,2,3),Units=c('X','Y','Z'))
  knitr::kable(d1,format='html', caption = "Table 1") %>%
    kable_styling(position='float_left',full_width=F)


    knitr::kable(d1,format='html', caption = "Table 2") %>%
    kable_styling(position='float_left',full_width=F)

      knitr::kable(d1,format='html', caption = "Table 3") %>%
    kable_styling(position='left',full_width=F)

```    
# Next heading
````

[image]